# How do I store an array of <divs> in local storage in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am making an E-commerce website and facing a problem in shopping cart part.

I defined my shopping cart as an array. When an user clicked AddToCart button it will store that < div > element of the item in the array. I want to store this array in local storage or any kind of storage. This is what I have now.

```
<script>
    function check() {
      console.log(shoppingCart);
      localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(shoppingCart));
      items = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("users"));
      console.log(localStorage);
    }
  </script>
```

My Firefox console tab gives me this when I added two items.

```
Array [ div.item, div.item]                      products.html:88:15
Storage { shoppingCart: "[{},{}]", length: 1 }   products.html:91:15
```

So two items were added to the local storage. But instead of an array of < div > elements it gives an array of empty objects.

My question is how do I add an array of html < div > elements in local storage (or any other kind of storage) so that my shoppingcart list will remain after I reload the webpage.

Thank you for reading my question, I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: Divs (HTMLElements) are Objects, with no own properties. When you stringify them, you get `{}`. Maybe you want to store the actual HTML, instead of the elements, since localStorage can only store strings. Something like `JSON.stringify(shoppingCart.map(el => el.outerHTML))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't be storing `div` elements at all, since people won't be buying `div` elements from you and there's no reason to bloat up `localStorage` with data and UI layer content. Instead, store the data that those elements contain and later, when you need to get that data out of storage, you can create `div` elements (or any UI) to hold them for display on the page.

Here's an example that shows why it's better to not store the presentation with the data. I'll show you that I can create two different presentations from one set of data (it won't work here in the Stack Overflow snippet environment, but it will here in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h5mnboL/3/)):

```js
let cart = [];
const list = document.querySelector("select");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  cart.push(list.value); // Update the cart
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart)); // store cart
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
});

document.querySelector("#show").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Presentation #1

  // Loop over all the items in the array that is created by
  // converting the JSON in local storage to an array
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")).forEach(function(item){
    let row = document.createElement("div"); // make a div for the item
    row.textContent = item; // populate the div
    document.body.appendChild(row); // Put item in doc.
  });
  
  
  // Presentation #2

  // Same data and same technique to access it
  
  let tbl = document.createElement("table");
  
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")).forEach(function(item){
    // But different presentation
    let row = document.createElement("tr"); 
    let cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.textContent = item; // populate the div
    row.appendChild(cell);
    tbl.appendChild(row);
  });  
  
  document.body.appendChild(tbl); // Put item in doc.
  
});
```

```css
table, td {
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Item 1</option>
  <option>Item 2</option>
  <option>Item 3</option>
  <option>Item 4</option>
  <option>Item 5</option>
  <option>Item 6</option>  
</select>
<button>Add to cart</button>
<button id="show">Show Cart</button>
```

Comment: I am also working with phpmyadmin. There I have created a database for my products. Is it a better idea to store the names of my products in stead of div elements?  Also thank you for your answer !

Comment: @taikikun Yes. As I said, you aren't selling `div` elements. Keep your back-end data separate from your front-end presentation. What happens if down the line you want to display what's in the cart in some other element? If you store the presentation with the data, you have tight coupling between two layers and loose coupling is always better.

Comment: My initial idea was to create a database for shopping cart in mySQL. But since I didn't see an importance of storing that information in my server. I decided to store it in local storage (or cookie) by using JavaScript. Thanks for enlightening me, I appreciate that!

Comment: @taikikun You're welcome. Check out my updated answer which shows a little more clearly the benefit of separating the data from the presentation and don't forget to mark this as "the" answer, by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.